# Mongoid - Get all integer values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, mongoid

I have the following mongoid Model

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :myField
end
```

The value stored against `myField` can be of any datatype. I need to filter out, how many times an integer was stored against this field, or how many times a string was stored as the value.

Is there any way this can be done?

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is a build-in mongo feature.

```
MyModel.where(:field.with_type => 2).count  # Number of strings
MyModel.where(:field.with_type => 16).count # Number of 32-bit integers
```

http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html

`2` and `16` represent the BSON type for a string and a 32-bit integer.

For a complete list of BSON types and their corresponding numbers see:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#op._S_type